# Search box in Windows 11 emoji panel does not work

Tags: windows-11, search, emoji

The Windows 11 emoji panel/picker/keyboard (opened by <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>) contains a search field, but it does not work. You can see the text cursor in this screenshot, but it is not blinking even after clicking in the field with the mouse, and I am unable to enter anything into the field.

[image]

When I go to the "smileys" tab, the text box changes (it now reads `search emojis`) but the field is unresponsive as well.

[image]

**EDIT:**

1. I found that disabling AutoHotkey makes the search box work, so clearly the problem is with an AutoHotkey script. I will investigate and update again!

Comment: @John do you have the same problem even when not using AutoHotkey?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular search"?

Comment: @John - The author is attempting to find an emoji not a file.

Comment: Is your keyboard layout US English ?

Comment: @harrymc the keyboard layout should be irrelevant to a text-entry box, no? Yes my layout is US Eng, but the AHK script is reading the key presses and returns a different layout instead.

Comment: This question then revolves around your AutoHotkey script, so can't be answered as-is.